# How to see accuracy breakdown by class in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I am attempting to create a neural network using a softmax classifier with N=26 classes. Initial results seem promising, but I need to know the accuracy breakdown by class. After 150 epochs, the test accuracy is 71.1%, but that's the total of 26 classes. I am certain there are some classes doing really well and some doing really poorly, and I need to know which are which and what the accuracy is per each class.

I have spent *days* searching and cannot figure out how to get that. It seems like this would be a basic, simple, *obvious* thing that someone would need, so I suspect I'm just missing something.

I tried `print(tf.print(tf.compat.v1.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy(labels, logits, n)))` but got

```
name: "PrintV2"
op: "PrintV2"
input: "StringFormat"
attr {
  key: "end"
  value {
    s: "\n"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "output_stream"
  value {
    s: "stderr"
  }
}
```

I tried removing the tf.print and tried `print(tf.compat.v1.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy(labels, logits, n))` but got `(<tf.Tensor 'mean_accuracy/mean_accuracy:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'mean_accuracy/update_op:0' shape=(27,) dtype=float32>)`. Neither of which are errors, technically, but neither do they tell me what I need to know.

I also tried `print(classification_report(labels, logits))` and `print(classification_report(labels, tf.argmax(logits)))`, both of which gave me the error `TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len()`. Logits is the tensor. I've been unable to find a way to convert it to an array or vector, or even print the contents of it.

How do I see the accuracy breakdown by class? (In case it isn't obvious what I mean by that, when 71% is the overall accuracy, I want it to tell me, for example: class 1 = 82%, ..., class N = 13%.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're content with finding class-level accuracy after training rather than during it,  you can simply `predict` your model's output on the test set and do the accuracy checking yourself by, e.g., storing hits and misses for each of the 26 classes in an array.

If you prefer, you can also use `tf.math.confusion_matrix`. This will calculate more information than you're looking for (it categorizes all of the misclassifications in a neat way), and you can then process the information to generate percentages.